# Salted butter in toffee

Tags: butter, candy, toffee

What effects would using salted butter instead of unsalted butter have on a toffee recipe?

I'm using the basic

- Equal parts butter and sugar
- Heat to soft crack (285 F)
- Poor into flat cooking sheet or something similar to cool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides the obvious - your toffee will have more salt in it? Salted butter also contains more water than unsalted butter, and varies more on both salt and moisture content on a brand-by-brand basis than unsalted butter. A higher percent of water means less fat, so after the water cooks out, your ratio of fat to sugar will be off somewhat.

Comment: Great!  That bit about the fat to sugar ratio is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK salted butter has typically 1 to 1.5 percent less fat than unsalted butter, not more water. The salt mostly displaces fat in the manufacturing process. Butter is typically a product with more than 80% dairy fat. If the manufacturer goes to 1% salt (400mg sodium per 100g) it has ~0.8% less fat. No much to worry about

Comment: I think that you guys should go and comment in http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13782/what-different-uses-do-we-assign-to-salted-butter-vs-unsalted-butter as none of the answers mention anything about the water/fat content of the butter